# How to decrease RPi image capture time?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, image, webcam

I have two camera connected to RPi (1 USB camera and 1 RPi camera). I need to capture both images to do some processing on them right after image capture

I have this code:

```
file1 = 'imagecapture' + '_view1.png'
file2 = 'imagecapture'  + '_view2.png'
p1 = subprocess.Popen(
    "sudo raspistill -t 1500 -o {} -w 1920 -h 1080".format(file1), shell=True)

p2 = subprocess.Popen(
    "fswebcam -S 20 --resolution 1920x1080  --rotate -90 --device /dev/video1 {}".format(file2), shell=True)
p1.wait()
p2.wait()
time.sleep(0.2)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The `sleep` I have added to make sure that image is captured and saved in the directory before I read it again and so some processing (I tested it and 2 seconds is sufficient).

This whole process takes 7-8 seconds. How can I make it even quicker? Is it possible to make it 3-4 seconds?

RPi Specs:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

RPi camera: rpi imx477

Comment: Sorry, I meant capture takes 1-2 seconds so total 3-4 seconds. Updated the question. I want to reduce the time to half or as low as possible.

Comment: WHY would you want to run a python script JUST to run 2 command line programs? Just run from a script - better run 2 which will probably use the multiple processors on the Pi4 to run simultaneously!

Comment: @Milliways I have more things in the script, I only shared a snippet. The code I shared saves the images captured by Rpi before performing any processing on them. I 'need' to save the images somewhere before I do processing.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the camera as a video stream.

---

Or

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)

camera.start_preview()
camera.capture(my_stream, 'jpeg')
sleep(5)
camera.stop_preview()
```

---

Also doing this in C or C++ which are compiled languages will be faster.  Interrupted languages like python have to be re-interrupted each time.

---

https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/29/common-errors-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module/

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I dont need preview because I remotely connected to it. When you write sleep(5), does it mean it takes 5 seconds to store the capture?

Comment: The 5 seconds is the preview is active for 5 seconds before quitting.  You can probably go with out the start and stop preview, you just won't get an on screen preview.